# How do you wait on an input dialog in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am interested in displaying an input dialog and once the user enters the name of the node in the dialog I would like to create a tree node with the name they entered.

I am creating the edit dialog and then adding the node all in the same function but the behavior that I am seeing is that the tree node appears before the dialog appears or before the user even gets a chance to submit the name for the node, meaning the rest of the code that is included after displaying the dialog doesn't wait for the dialog to return the input.

Is there a way to provide an input dialog and wait for completion before taking another action?

Here is my code - The add() method calls editKey() method and then adds the node.

I expected to be able to wait for the input for each key and build the tag name before the rest of the code in the add function continues but that appears not to be the case:

```
public void add(){
    log.debug("node=<" + node.getValue() + ">");
    Node saveNode = node;
    if (node.getInfo().isList() || 
        node.getInfo().isLeafList()){
        try{
            TreeHelper treeHelper = (TreeHelper)device.getTreeHelper();
            Node n = treeHelper.getSchemaNode(node, node.getTagPath());
            if (n != null){
                if (node.getInfo().isList()){
                    log.debug("node<" + node.getName() + " is a list!");
                    String tagName = "";
                    if (n.getKeys().size() > 0){
                        for(String key: n.getKeys()){
                          node = n.getChildren().get(key); 
                          if (node != null){
                              editKey(node);
                          }
                          if (tagName.equals("")){
                            tagName += node.getValue();
                          }else{
                              tagName += "-" + node.getValue();
                          }
                        }
                    }
                    n.setTag(tagName);
                    n.getInfo().setListEntry(true);
                    n.getNodeTypes().remove("List");
                    n.getNodeTypes().add("ListEntry");
                    node = saveNode;
                }else if (node.getInfo().isLeafList()){
                    log.debug("node <" + node.getName() + "> is a leaf list!");
                    n.getInfo().setLeafListEntry(true);
                    n.getNodeTypes().remove("LeafList");
                    n.getNodeTypes().add("LeafListEntry");
                }
                addTreeNode(this.device,
                        selectedNode,
                        n,
                        true,
                        true);
            }else{
                log.debug("schema node is null for node <" + node.getName() + ">");
            }

       }catch(Exception e){
            log.error(IO.stackTrace(e));
       }
       selectedNode.setExpanded(true); 
    }
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("treeForm:treeSingle");
}
```

Here is the editKey() function:

```
public void editKey(Node node) throws Exception{
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    UIViewRoot rootView = ctx.getViewRoot();
    Dialog dialog = (Dialog)rootView.findComponent("editDialog");

    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.setModal(true);

    dialog.getChildren().clear();

    UIForm form = new UIForm();
    form.getChildren().clear();

    PanelGrid panel = new PanelGrid();
    panel.setColumns(2);

    OutputLabel label = new OutputLabel();
    label.setValue(node.getName());
    label.setFor("valueId");
    panel.getChildren().add(label);

    if (node.getDataTypes().contains("BOOL") ||
        (node.getValue() != null && 
        (node.getValue().equals("false") || node.getValue().equals("true")))){
        SelectOneMenu menu = new SelectOneMenu();
        ValueExpression valueExpression = createValueExpression("#{treeBean.node.value}");
        menu.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);
        menu.setId("valueId");
        menu.setLabel(node.getName());
        if (node.getValue() != null &&
            node.getValue().equals("false")){
            UISelectItem item = new UISelectItem();
            item.setItemLabel("false");
            item.setItemValue("false");
            menu.getChildren().add(item);
            item = new UISelectItem();
            item.setItemLabel("true");
            item.setItemValue("true");
            menu.getChildren().add(item);
        }else{
            UISelectItem item = new UISelectItem();
            item.setItemLabel("true");
            item.setItemValue("true");
            menu.getChildren().add(item);                
            item = new UISelectItem();
            item.setItemLabel("false");
            item.setItemValue("false");
            menu.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        panel.getChildren().add(menu);
    }else if (node.getEnums().size() > 0){
        SelectOneMenu menu = new SelectOneMenu();
        ValueExpression valueExpression = createValueExpression("#{treeBean.node.value}");
        menu.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);
        menu.setId("valueId");
        menu.setLabel(node.getName());
        for(String s : node.getEnums()){
            int index = s.indexOf(":");
            if (index != -1){
                s = s.substring(0, index);
            }
            UISelectItem item = new UISelectItem();
            item.setItemLabel(s);
            item.setItemValue(s);
            menu.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        panel.getChildren().add(menu);
    }else{
        InputText inputText = new InputText();
        ValueExpression valueExpression = createValueExpression("#{treeBean.node.value}");
        inputText.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);
        inputText.setId("valueId");
        inputText.setLabel(node.getName());
        inputText.setType("text");
        panel.getChildren().add(inputText);
    }
    UIOutput output = new UIOutput();
    output.setValue("Data types:  ");
    panel.getChildren().add(output);
    output = new UIOutput();
    output.setValue(node.getDataTypes().toString().replace("]", "").replace("[", ""));
    panel.getChildren().add(output);

    output = new UIOutput();
    output.setValue("Min. occurs:  ");
    panel.getChildren().add(output);
    output = new UIOutput();
    output.setValue(node.getMinOccurs()+"");
    panel.getChildren().add(output);

    output = new UIOutput();
    output.setValue("Max. occurs:  ");
    panel.getChildren().add(output);
    output = new UIOutput();
    output.setValue(node.getMaxOccurs()+"");
    panel.getChildren().add(output);


    form.getChildren().add(panel);


    CommandButton button = new CommandButton();
    button.setOnclick("$('#progress').show();$('#editDialog').hide();");
    button.setOncomplete("$('#progress').hide();$('#editDialog').hide();");
    button.setValue("submit");
    MethodExpression me = createMethodExpression("#{treeBean.save}");
    button.setActionExpression(me);

    form.getChildren().add(button);

    dialog.getChildren().add(form);

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("editDialog");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("editWidget.show()");


}
```

Comment: Hi, I am starting to wonder if I have been blacklisted on this site or something...:) Lately, I don't get any responses to my questions.

Comment: you're not blacklisted (doesn't exist afaik). Your code is awfully long, are yousure you need it all? Also, show the relevent part of your JSF page.